# Precision in python

Tags: python

How can write a print statement in python that will print exactly 2 digits after decimal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
x = 4.12121212
print '%.2f' % x
```

Basically, the same way you'd do it in C with printf.

Comment: @Philando: As of Python 3.0 the formatting I propose should be preferred over this one. If you want your code to be future-proof, you should mind that. [Here is the relevant PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/).

Comment: @ Space_C0wb0: Agreed and thanks for the update :-) But considering the problem I am working on it's not much needed.

Answer (score 13):

```
print "{0:.2f}".format(your_number)
```

This is explained in detail in the [Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings).

Answer (score 3):

```
 f = 4.55556
 print "{0:.2f}".format(f)
```

There is also a special module for fixed point decimals. More: http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html

Answer (score 0):

this is django float format template tag, that may be interest for you to reading ...

at line 92 :

[django float format template tag](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/branches/releases/1.2.X/django/template/defaultfilters.py?rev=15738)

Answer (score 0):

Another efficient way of doing this is:

```
import sys
a = 0.5
sys.stdout.write(str('%0.2f'%a))
```